# Django Error - Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

When I first ran the server everything was fine and the project was running properly. But after few days when I ran the server again, it gave me an error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Django Project\first\manage.py", line 11, in main
>     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Django Project\first\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Django Project\first\manage.py", line 13, in main
>     raise ImportError(
> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
> ```

To be specific, I'm on Windows 10, using VS Code as my IDE (I've not setup any virtual environment).
Django version installed - 3.2.9
Python version installed - 3.10.0
PIP version installed - 21.2.3

Here is a screenshot of my Environment Variables
[[image: 1]

Comment: did you install django? you can check by using pip freeze

Comment: In your path, there is `Django Project`. You need to change it to not include space.

Comment: What's the result of `pip show django`?

Comment: Could you try to reinstall it?

Comment: @Yerycs I didn't understand. Could you elaborate a little please?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Django is properly installed in my laptop. `django-admin` and `pip show django` is working completely fine in PowerShell

Comment: `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Django Project\first\manage.py` This is your path. `Django Project` has space, you need to rename path to not include space.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. I deleted the project and created a new one and it worked. I hope I won't face any such issue while working on a big project!